# Java array resetting in a do/while loop?

Tags: java

For context this is a piles game where a user picks an element of an array then takes away a specified number and the one that picks up the last counter wins. So I question comes to looping because as the turn is up the array in the do/while loop resets and starts again.

```
do{
  if(userPicked == 1){
    System.out.println(player1 +" will start the game.");
    player1 = startingPlayer;
    player2 = secondPlayer;
  }else{
    System.out.println(player2+ " will start the game.");
    player2 = startingPlayer;
    player1 = secondPlayer;
  } //else
  gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed + 1; 
  System.out.println("The piles are.....");
  System.out.println("1 | " + piles [0]);
  System.out.println("2 | " + piles [1]);
  System.out.println("3 | " + piles [2]);
  System.out.println("4 | " + piles [3]);
  System.out.println("5 | " + piles [4]);


  do{  

    System.out.println(player2 + "First pick the pile you would like to minus from");
    System.out.println( "then pick the amount you would like to take away."); 
    int userPile = readInt ("What pile would you like to minus from");
    int userTokens = readInt("How many tokens would you like to take away");
    //the game goes below this 
    if(userPile == 1){
      System.out.println("1 | " + (piles [0] - userTokens));
      System.out.println("2 | " + piles [1]);
      System.out.println("3 | " + piles [2]);
      System.out.println("4 | " + piles [3]);
      System.out.println("5 | " + piles [4]);  
    }else if(userPile == 2){
      System.out.println("1 | " + piles [0]);
      System.out.println("2 | " + (piles [1] - userTokens));
      System.out.println("3 | " + piles [2]);
      System.out.println("4 | " + piles [3]);
      System.out.println("5 | " + piles [4]);  
    }else if(userPile == 3){
      System.out.println("1 | " + piles [0]);
      System.out.println("2 | " + piles [1]);
      System.out.println("3 | " + (piles [2] - userTokens));
      System.out.println("4 | " + piles [3]);
      System.out.println("5 | " + piles [4]);
    }else if(userPile == 4){
      System.out.println("1 | " + piles [0]);
      System.out.println("2 | " + piles [1]);
      System.out.println("3 | " + piles [2]);
      System.out.println("4 | " + (piles [3] - userTokens));
      System.out.println("5 | " + piles [4]);
    }else if(userPile == 5){
      System.out.println("1 | " + piles [0]);
      System.out.println("2 | " + piles [1]);
      System.out.println("3 | " + piles [2]);
      System.out.println("4 | " + piles [3]);
      System.out.println("5 | " + (piles [4] - userTokens));
    }else{
      System.out.println("An error occured"); 
    }//else

    System.out.println(player1 + "First pick the pile you would like to minus from");
    System.out.println( "then pick the amount you would like to take away."); 
    int userPile2 = readInt ("What pile would you like to minus from");
    int userTokens2 = readInt("How many tokens would you like to take away");
    //the game goes below this 
    if(userPile == 1){
      System.out.println("1 | " + (piles [0] - userTokens2));
      System.out.println("2 | " + piles [1]);
      System.out.println("3 | " + piles [2]);
      System.out.println("4 | " + piles [3]);
      System.out.println("5 | " + piles [4]);  
    }else if(userPile == 2){
      System.out.println("1 | " + piles [0]);
      System.out.println("2 | " + (piles [1] - userTokens2));
      System.out.println("3 | " + piles [2]);
      System.out.println("4 | " + piles [3]);
      System.out.println("5 | " + piles [4]);  
    }else if(userPile == 3){
      System.out.println("1 | " + piles [0]);
      System.out.println("2 | " + piles [1]);
      System.out.println("3 | " + (piles [2] - userTokens2));
      System.out.println("4 | " + piles [3]);
      System.out.println("5 | " + piles [4]);
    }else if(userPile == 4){
      System.out.println("1 | " + piles [0]);
      System.out.println("2 | " + piles [1]);
      System.out.println("3 | " + piles [2]);
      System.out.println("4 | " + (piles [3] - userTokens));
      System.out.println("1 | " + piles [4]);
    }else if(userPile == 5){
      System.out.println("1 | " + piles [0]);
          System.out.println("1 | " + piles [1]);
          System.out.println("1 | " + piles [2]);
          System.out.println("1 | " + piles [3]);
          System.out.println("5 | " + (piles [4] - userTokens));
        }else{
          System.out.println("An error occured"); 
        }//else  


      }while (piles [0] + piles [1] + piles [2] + piles [3] + piles [4] > 1 );
```

If anyone knows how to keep the array that has had numbers taken off it as a constant even after both players have had a turn that would be great. (Also if we could keep the programming talk to somewhat of a down low as I have only being doing this for 6 weeks)

Thanks for any help in advance this has had me stuck for a while.

Comment: Where is `piles` declared? For the question, include all the relevant code, and cut out all unnecessary code (like all the print lines).

Comment: Use static ArrayList<Integer> to store data, and never use do-while, it's bad template as goTo=), it's better to use usual while loop.

Comment: @Geisterkirche I can't agree with "never use do-while". There are many cases where do-while leads to cleaner code. Use the right construct for the job.

Comment: @Carcigenicate =) i, can't agree with you too, it exists in java only for back-compatibility cases, and for simple code like this no reasons to use do-while, usual while simplier, and it means better.

Comment: @Geisterkirche I'm almost certain you're mistaken. I've used them many times, and after comparing them against a normal while loop, found them to be cleaner. If they aren't leading to cleaner code, they're being used incorrectly, and that's the fault of the author, not the construct.

Comment: After a couple minutes of searching, I can't find a single article saying that they're unconditionally bad. It's a "time and place" scenario.

Comment: @Carcigenicate =) It's Stroustrups words, i'm only agree with him.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Do-while loops lead to too many mistakes, see the code at top=) , author skiped 1 line with conditions, so i think, when you have conditions after so long code block, especially if there another do-while inside, you obfuscate logic. Such constructions must be simple, simple enought to be less than one screen in height.

Comment: No doubt that long do-while loops can lead to many mistakes, an so can long conditionals, short-named variables, huge functions, too-deep nested blocks, etc. I see no vulnerability in do-whiles that can't suffer other logical structures in the hands of a novice programmer. @Geisterkirche "Simple enough to be less than one screen in height": I agree 100% with that, but that's appliable to all coding in general (and is no reason to leave do-whiles appart).

Comment: @Geisterkirche He never said never to use them, he said he prefers normal while loops.

Comment: Or at least the quote from him that I saw didn't have him unconditionally rejecting them. I'd much rather have non-duplicated code, than a condition that's potentially off screen. Historically, the former has caused far more headaches for me

Answer (score 0):

Since there is still no answer and there isn't also the required feedback (a [complete, minimal and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), I can only suggest some good practices in coding which will help you avoid, and eventually find the cause of your problems:

- Avoid long methods: It is better to distribute it functionally between several methods (typically *private* methods). Among other things, that makes you **name** each method, and so, you will find that your coded algorithm is **readable**:

`public void extractAllData(parameters...)
    {
        if (validateParameters(...))
        {
            a=extractPrimaryData(...);
            if (existSecondaryData(a))
            {
                b=extractSecondaryData(...);
             }
        }
        return a+b;
    }`

- Try **not to repeat** structures: If two blocks of code are very similar, only different for some number or expression, it is better to extract them to a **common [private] method**, and make the differences be **parameters** to that method. You'll save yourself a lot of time.
- Do not index arrays with explicit constants: `a[0], a[1], a[2]`, etc. Get accostumed to index with a variable: `a[i]`. And, if you want to traverse all the elements of the array, this variable must be the index of a `for` loop:

`for (int i=0; i < array.length;i++)
    {
        doSomething(a[i]);
    }`

In this way, the length of the array should be present just at the moment of initializing it. And from then on, use `array.length` always.

Comment: While this is more of a code review than anything, I agree. One of the biggest lessons I've learned in the past year is learning to extract common code into functions. Writing code becomes significantly easier once you grasp that. Figure out what stays the same, and what changes, and make a function out of it.